# An error when sending an base on a search result

Tags: php, sql

I have this hospital app where I type in a specific patient's name and it is supposed to return possible donor matches based on blood type which it is.

[image: app ui]

The problem is when I click on the send button it sends it to all of the results, all the results have same email for testing, except the real recipient and the patient name and details though correct is appearing multiple times

This is my code

```
 $link= new mysqli('localhost','root','');
    if($link->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed:" .$link->connect_error);
    }
      mysqli_select_db($link,"blood_organ_donation");

$sendtoperson= $_POST['send']; //send message to person found from search result
//Take contents of the search box
//mail function parameters, send two sets of messages depending on blood/organ donation
    $firstname=$_SESSION["firstname"];
    $fathername=$_SESSION["fathername"];
    $lastname=$_SESSION["lastname"];
        $pbloodtype="SELECT personprofile.firstname,personprofile.lastname,personprofile.fathername,personprofile.email,bloodtype.blood_type,personprofile.bloodoner 
        FROM personprofile,bloodtype 
        WHERE personprofile.bloodtype=bloodtype.id AND personprofile.hospitaladmission=134 ";
        $fetchbloodtype=  mysqli_query($link,$pbloodtype);   //doner query
        $processblood=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchbloodtype);
        while($processblood= mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchbloodtype)){
        $query ="SELECT personprofile.firstname,personprofile.fathername,personprofile.lastname,bloodtype.blood_type,hospital.hospitalname,hospital.geolocation
        FROM personprofile,bloodtype,hospital
        WHERE   firstname= '$firstname' AND lastname= '$lastname' AND fathername= '$fathername'
        AND personprofile.bloodtype=bloodtype.id AND personprofile.hospitaladmission=hospital.id";
        $fetchemail=  mysqli_query($link,$query); //patient query
        $process=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchemail);
        // Send the blood donation email if person is blood donner
        if($processblood['bloodoner']=="Yes" && $processblood['blood_type']==$process['blood_type']){ //with same bloodtype
        $to=$processblood['email'];
        $header= "Blood is needed urgently";
       // $messagebody= "Patient Name: ".$processtable['firstname']." ".$processtable['fathername']." ".$processtable['lastname']."  "."Hospital Name:"; 
        $messagebody = "Patient Name: ".$process['firstname']." ".$process['fathername']." ".$process['lastname']."  "."Hospital Name:".PHP_EOL; 
        //$hyperlink= new DOMDocument();
        //$hyperlink->loadHTML("<html><body><a href='<".$processtable['geolocation']."'>" .$processtable['hospitalname']."</a></body></html>"); 
        $hyperlink = "<html><body><a href='<".$process['geolocation']."'>".$process['hospitalname']."</a></body></html>".PHP_EOL;
         //Name of the person that needs the blood transfusion along with hospital he is staying at,hyperlinked to its location
         $string .= $messagebody."  ".$hyperlink.PHP_EOL ;

    $message= "Dear"." ".$processblood['firstname']." ".$processblood['lastname'].",".PHP_EOL .$string; 
    if(isset($sendtoperson)){   
        if(mail($to,$header,$message)){
            echo "Sent";
        }
        else{ echo "Not sent";}
    }

    }//end of if person was blooddoner
    }
```

Comment: Could you print out ( or var dump ) your query results ($processblood and $process).

Comment: $processblood:
Ahmed Khram issa ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- Yes
Joseph Assaf John ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- No
Ash Moty Scott ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- Yes
Isacf maca jaack ahmed_issaigcse@hotmail.com B- Yes
Ashley Maker Make ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- Yes
Ashley Maker Make ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- Yes
James Make Ma ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- Yes 
cd cd cd ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B-Yes 
cde cde cde ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B-No
Marc Anderson Mac ismaeelissa@hotmail.com B- No

$process:
Noora issa Khram B- Islamic Health Institution https://www.google.com/maps/place/Isla.

Comment: Your code potentially is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Also **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Given that this app seems to be intended to store sensitive medical records I am a bit concerned about your lack of basic security or data protection knowledge. Perhaps someone more experienced ought to be advising you on this project.

Comment: @ahmedk According to the data you posted in the comment you should get 7/10 emails that have the bloodtype B- and Yes for doner. Worked as intended when i ran the same code just the data in array, so your queries and that while loop might be the problem, in case you receive more than 7/10 emails.